# How to prove series convergence: $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n+\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sqrt{2+n^2}\right)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have this series:
$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n+\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sqrt{2+n^2}\right)^2$$
I know that it's convergent (from WolframAlpha) but I need to prove it is convergent. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $$\begin{align*} \dfrac 1 n+\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sqrt{2+n^2}&=\frac1n+\frac{(\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sqrt{2+n^2})\cdot(\sqrt{1+n^2}+\sqrt{2+n^2})}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+\sqrt{2+n^2}}=\\\\&=\frac1n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+\sqrt{2+n^2}}\\& \le \frac{1}{n} \end{align*}$$ Then the convergence is established by squaring both sides and using the comparison test.

---

For the above implication to be correct we also need to show that the middle part is positive. Indeed $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+\sqrt{2+n^2}}\ < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}+\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{1}{2n}$$ or equivalently $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+\sqrt{2+n^2}}\ >-\frac{1}{2n}$$ which implies that $$\frac1n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}+\sqrt{2+n^2}}>\frac1n-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac1{2n}>0$$

Comment: But comparison test needs $\sum_1^n\frac1n$ to be convergent, but it isn't. @Stefanos

Comment: @user23791 Square both sides firstly....

Comment: Simple and elegant, but you have to show that middle part is positive, not just smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$ (It is too obvious, but maybe for the OP)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\dfrac 1 n+\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sqrt{2+n^2}\sim _\infty \dfrac 1 n$.

Comment: But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n$ doesn't converge. How will it help me?

Comment: @user23791 Don't forget the square.

Comment: @user23791 If you wish you can read my hint as $\left(\dfrac 1 n+\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sqrt{2+n^2}\right)^2\sim _\infty \left(\dfrac 1 n\right)^2$.